# need recent version of libmemcached on aws ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, yum, memcached

The yum repo available on aws ec2 instances only has an old version of [libmemcached](http://libmemcached.org/libMemcached.html): v 1.0.8.

**Can anyone tell me how to get a more recent version, like 1.0.18, installed on an aws ec2 instance?**

Which external yum repo [can I add](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/add-repositories.html) to install a more recent versioneven if it is unsupported?

## EC2: yum info libmemcached

```
Using username "ec2-user".
Authenticating with public key "imported-openssh-key"

       __|  __|_  )
       _|  (     /   Amazon Linux AMI
      ___|\___|___|

https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/2015.09-release-notes/
No packages needed for security; 1 packages available
Run "sudo yum update" to apply all updates.
[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx ~]$ yum info libmemcached
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
Available Packages
Name        : libmemcached
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 1.0.8
Release     : 2.6.amzn1
Size        : 246 k
Repo        : amzn-main/2015.09
Summary     : Client library and command line tools for memcached server
URL         : http://libmemcached.org/
License     : BSD
Description : libmemcached is a C/C++ client library and tools for the memcached server
            : (http://memcached.org/). It has been designed to be light on memory
            : usage, and provide full access to server side methods.
            :
            : It also implements several command line tools:
            :
            : memcapable  Checking a Memcached server capibilities and compatibility
            : memcat      Copy the value of a key to standard output
            : memcp       Copy data to a server
            : memdump     Dumping your server
            : memerror    Translate an error code to a string
            : memexist    Check for the existance of a key
            : memflush    Flush the contents of your servers
            : memparse    Parse an option string
            : memping     Test to see if a server is available.
            : memrm       Remove a key(s) from the server
            : memslap     Generate testing loads on a memcached cluster
            : memstat     Dump the stats of your servers to standard output
            : memtouch    Touches a key
```

## EC2: cat /etc/yum.repos.d/amzn-main.repo

```
[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx~]$ cat /etc/yum.repos.d/amzn-main.repo
[amzn-main]
name=amzn-main-Base
mirrorlist=http://repo.$awsregion.$awsdomain/$releasever/main/mirror.list
mirror_expire=300
metadata_expire=300
priority=10
failovermethod=priority
fastestmirror_enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-amazon-ga
enabled=1
retries=5
timeout=10
report_instanceid=yes

[amzn-main-debuginfo]
name=amzn-main-debuginfo
mirrorlist=http://repo.$awsregion.$awsdomain/$releasever/main/debuginfo/mirror.list
mirror_expire=300
metadata_expire=300
priority=10
failovermethod=priority
fastestmirror_enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-amazon-ga
enabled=0
retries=5
timeout=10
report_instanceid=yes
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still trying to get a solution using an external repo as @Jukka suggests but until I do, I was able to compile it with the following:

```
sudo -i 
yum remove libmemcached.x86_64

yum install bzr.x86_64
yum install gcc-c++

mkdir -p /tmp/memcached
cd /tmp/memcached
wget https://launchpad.net/libmemcached/1.0/1.0.18/+download/libmemcached-1.0.18.tar.gz
tar -zxvf libmemcached-1.0.18.tar.gz
cd /tmp/memcached/
bzr branch lp:libmemcached
cd libmemcached
./bootstrap.sh autoreconf
NOTE YOU GET THE FOLLOWING ERROR BUT CONTINUE ANYWAY: "./bootstrap.sh:315: An attempt was made to set an invalid VENDOR="
cd ../libmemcached-1.0.18
./configure
make
make test
make install
```

Comment: I got this

clients/memflush.cc: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
clients/memflush.cc:42:22: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
   if (opt_servers == false)
                      ^~~~~
clients/memflush.cc:51:24: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
     if (opt_servers == false)
                        ^~~~~
make[1]: *** [clients/memflush.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/memcached/libmemcached-1.0.18'
make: *** [all] Error 2

Answer (score 1):

You could try Remi's RPM repo. http://blog.remirepo.net/pages/Config-en

Note that it depends on EPEL and that you need to explicitly enable it when installing packages:

```
yum --enablerepo=remi install XXX
```

NOTE: not sure if it is compatible with Amazon Linux though. If not, consider utilizing CentOS 7 which has 1.0.16 by default.

Comment: The URL I posted points to a guide on how to set up the repo.

Comment: as per their directions at your link  I tried: cd /etc/yum.repos.d,
wget wget http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi.repo, then yum --enablerepo=remi install libmemcached but I get the error: ould not retrieve mirrorlist http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/2014.09/remi/mirror error was
14: PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"

Comment: Looks like Amazon Linux is not directly compatible with the repo. If you look at the .repo file, you see that the $releasever variable resolves to something (2014.09) other than what the repo is expecting (i.e. standard EL version strings, 6.4 etc)